# Changing modelformset labels

Tags: django, django-models, formset

I have created a modelformset for voting on multiple subtitles. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to change the "Vote:" label to the names of the different subtitles instead (so if the subtitles are A, B and C, A should be before the first field, B for the second field etc.). How can I change this?

The modelformset is created in the views.py like this:

```
VoteFormSet = modelformset_factory(YesNoVote, form=YesNoVotingForm, extra=3)
```

YesNoVotingForm looks like this:

```
class YesNoVotingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
            model = YesNoVote
            fields = ['vote',]
            widgets = {
                'vote': forms.Select(attrs={"required": True}), 
            }
```

and this is the yesnovote model:

```
class YesNoVote(models.Model):
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    vote = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False, related_name="yesnovote_user", null=True)
    election = models.ForeignKey(YesNoElection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="yesnovote")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} stemde {self.vote} bij {self.subtitle} (vallend onder {self.election})"
```

and this is the html page:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_data }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
    <br> 
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" name = "voting" class="btn btn-primary save">Submit</button>
    Let op: Je kunt je stem niet meer wijzigen.
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have exact number of formsets try:

in views.py add formset for modelformset_factory:

VoteFormSet = modelformset_factory(YesNoVote, form=YesNoVotingForm, extra=3, formset=YesNoVoteModelFormSet)

in forms.py create:

class YesNoVoteModelFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    label_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
    for num, form in enumerate(self.forms):
        form.fields["vote"].label = label_list[num]
```

for more info go here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/models/#modelformset-factory